# Merge Duplicate Value and sum them in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get a sum of those duplicate FamilleArticleName in laravel
the code in controller :

```
 $totalFamillyValeur = Article::select('FamilleArticle','ArticleStock','ArticlePrixunit',DB::raw('(articles.ArticleStock*articles.ArticlePrixunit) as Valeur'))
        //->groupBy('FamilleArticle')
        ->get();

    $datavs =[];

    $totalFamillyValeur->map(function ($item) use (&$datavs){
        $datavs[] =$item->Valeur;
    });

    $datapvs =[];
    $totalpervs = array_sum($datavs);

    $totalFamillyValeur->map(function ($item) use (&$datapvs){

        //$dataps["qty"][] =number_format ( ($item->Stock/$totalpers )*100,2);
        $datapvs["FamilleArticleName"][] = $item->FamilleArticle;
        $datapvs["valeur"][] =  number_format ($item->Valeur);
    });
```

the result in array

```
 "FamilleArticleName" => array:6 [
0 => "522.52209"
1 => "522.52206"
2 => "515.51511"
3 => "512.51201"
4 => "515.51504"
5 => "515.51504"
]
"valeur" => array:6 [
0 => "7,488"
1 => "750"
2 => "675"
3 => "325"
4 => "1,250"
5 => "1,250"
  ]]
```

and i want to get those duplicates data to be sum and grouped based on the famillearticle name

like this :

```
0 => "522.52209"
1 => "522.52206"
2 => "515.51511"
3 => "512.51201"
4 => "515.51504"
]
"valeur" => array:6 [
0 => "7,488"
1 => "750"
2 => "675"
3 => "325"
4 => "2,500"
  ]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_sum](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) and [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get the sums of each.

First, we have to get all the keys then sum them with array_sum and array_column.

```
$totalFamillyValeur = Article::select('FamilleArticle','ArticleStock','ArticlePrixunit',DB::raw('(articles.ArticleStock*articles.ArticlePrixunit) as Valeur'))
    //->groupBy('FamilleArticle')
    ->get();

$datavs =[];

$totalFamillyValeur->map(function ($item) use (&$datavs){
    $datavs[] =$item->Valeur;
});

$datapvs =[];
$totalpervs = array_sum($datavs);

$totalFamillyValeur->map(function ($item) use (&$datapvs){

    //$dataps["qty"][] =number_format ( ($item->Stock/$totalpers )*100,2);
    $datapvs["FamilleArticleName"][] = $item->FamilleArticle;
    $datapvs["valeur"][] =  number_format ($item->Valeur);
});

// remove duplicate keys
$keys = array_unique($datapvs["valeur"]);

// sum values with same key from $arr and save to $sums
foreach($keys as $key){
  $sums[$key] = array_sum(array_column($datapvs["valeur"],$key));    
}

var_dump($sums);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sir Jubair, i want to this to generate a chart with charjs but i have issue to generate them in array with two values FamilleArticleName & Valeur

Comment: Did you get familler output with my answer! if yes then just replace the data with foreach with your chartjs conent

Comment: i got it as a null   "7,488" => 0
  750 => 0
  675 => 0
  325 => 0
  "1,250" => 0

Comment: I have edited my answer try on inside your foreach "$sums[$key] = array_sum(array_column($datapvs["valeur"],$key))"

Comment: it's still null do you have any contact i could send you a screenshot

Comment: upload your screenshot to your drive and share the linked in here

Comment: i solve it brother thank you i was missing a sum and a groupby

Answer (score 0):

I found the error in the old code i need to add a sum and use the groupBy:

```
$totalFamillyValeur = Article::select('FamilleArticle','ArticleStock','ArticlePrixunit',DB::raw('(articles.ArticleStock*articles.ArticlePrixunit) as Valeur'))
//->groupBy('FamilleArticle')
->get();
```

the new code :

```
$totalFamillyValeur = Article::select('FamilleArticle','ArticleStock','ArticlePrixunit',DB::raw('sum(articles.ArticleStock*articles.ArticlePrixunit) as Valeur'))
    ->groupBy('FamilleArticle')
    ->get();
```

I posted this answer if someone wanted to Multiple two columns and sum the duplicated data he could make it like this.